# Preferred way of developing web applications with m2eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

When developing Maven web applications I usually resort the the `jetty-maven-plugin` to quickly launch my application for local testing and debugging. Using the launch with `m2eclipse` has the drawback of not properly including all sources for debugging, even though they are downloaded by Maven ( see [Source lookup does not seem to work](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-983) ).

What is the preferred way to debug Maven web applications in Eclipse? I'd especially appreciate configurations which work with the `gwt-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Are there any additional pros using m2eclipse over WTP tools for testing and debuging webapps inside eclipse?

Comment: @cetnar: m2eclipse allows me to use maven for all things mavenish, such as dependencies, plugins etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My preferred way to develop web applications with m2eclipse is to... not use it. Instead, I use the approach described in [Debugging with the Maven Jetty Plugin in Eclipse](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+with+the+Maven+Jetty+Plugin+inside+Eclipse) that I'm quoting below:

> **Step 1**
>
> Go to the Run/External Tools/External
>   Tools ..." menu item on the "Run" menu
>   bar. Select "Program" and click the
>   "New" button. On the "Main" tab, fill
>   in the "Location:" as the full path to
>   your "`mvn`" executable. For the
>   "Working Directory:" select the
>   workspace that matches your webapp.
>   For "Arguments:" add `jetty:run`.
>
> Move to the "Environment" tab and
>   click the "New" button to add a new
>   variable named `MAVEN_OPTS` with the
>   value:
>
> ```
> -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=y
> ```
>
> If you supply `suspend=n` instead of
>   `suspend=y` you can start immediately
>   without running the debugger and
>   launch the debugger at anytime you
>   really wish to debug.
>
> **Step 2**
>
> Then, pull up the "Run/Debug/Debug
>   ..." menu item and select "Remote Java
>   Application" and click the "New"
>   button. Fill in the dialog by
>   selecting your webapp project for the
>   "Project:" field, and ensure you are
>   using the same port number as you
>   specified in the `address=` property
>   above.
>
> Now all you need to do is to
>   Run/External Tools and select the name
>   of the maven tool setup you created in
>   step 1 to start the plugin and then
>   Run/Debug and select the name of the
>   debug setup you setup in step2.
>
> <sub>From instructions provided by
>   Rolf Strijdhorst on the Maven mailing
>   list</sub>
>
> **Stopping Jetty**
>
> In order to stop the jetty server the
>   "Allow termination of remote VM"
>   should be checked in debug dialog in
>   Step 2. When you have the jetty server
>   running and the debugger connected you
>   can switch to the debug perspective.
>   In the debug view, right click on the
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client
>   VM[localhost:4000] and  chose
>   terminate. This will stop the debugger
>   and the jetty server.

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid writing code which needs a container of some kind to debug. Always write code that can run independently and wrap it in a very thin layer for deployment (thin layer -> few lines of code -> few bugs).

If you really must, try [MockRunner](http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/) to emulate the app server.

Other than that, you can manually add the sources in the project properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with your statement about layering, but at times I do need to whole application running to debug integration issues, and that's when source lookup is most useful.

Comment: In that case, set breakpoints and add the sources to the project properties as you encounter the "missing source" view. It's a bit of manual work until the next version of m2eclipse is released.